# list item view as in the new play store app

Tags: android, user-interface, google-play

I am trying to figure out how has google coded the item view as seen in the screenshot here

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CtcAk0DkagM/UWOkdFlsGiI/AAAAAAAAABM/dcC0pqhNd6I/s1600/Play+Home+-+Phone.png]

I am refering to the Apps, Books, Music, list item views. I decompiled the apk, tried to mess around in the views to find which one would affect the desired view, but I can't really install the apk after signing it with another certificate. How do I go about finding the way they are coding that view?

Comment: Did it occur to you that they might be plain buttons?

Comment: When you say "how has google coded", are you referring to the way the data is visualized (layout) or the actual Java implementation of binding the data to views in a container? The layout could be as easy as a bunch of simple `TextView`s with some text, a 9-patch background, and compound drawable, in a `ViewGroup` to your liking. `GridView`, `GridLayout`, nested `LinearLayout`s would all do. Hell, you could even use a `ListView` that has two items per row. Plenty of options, so I guess the question is what you're really after?

Comment: @TimCastelijns They are not buttons, since the same kind of card ui is being used pretty much everywhere, even for dynamic content.

Comment: @MH I am talking about the card like ui element, with a shadow to it. 9 Patches are a solution, but they do not do justice to the rounded corners on HD screens. I need to do in code, using a custom view.

Comment: @Amit: if you supply appropriate 9-patches for the various density buckets, I don't see why the rounded corners wouldn't work out alright. As a matter of fact, that's exactly what these custom `PlayQuickLink` views do: `android:background="@drawable/card_bg_play"`. Since we're now nearing a grey area, that's all I'm going to say about this. As mentioned earlier: plenty of options to mimic this appearance both visually and code-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty simple layout - they are using a RelativeLayout with an ImageView for the picture and a TextView for the category name (Apps, Games...).

I used the HierachyViewer provided in the sdk (tools/monitor.bat) to analyze the layout. [image: Screenshot]

I'd recommend you use it to further explore the layouts.

Comment: Just something to be aware of: there's a little more to this than plain a `RelativeLayout`, `ImageView` and `TextView`. They form the basic ingredients, yes, but - except for the `TextView` - every single one of these is actually a custom view.